# unbale to select date using selenium webdriver and HTML code is there for calendar

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker, calendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQXPh.png)
below is the HTML for date input field.i am unable to inspect the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether DatePicker is present or not, pass the locator of the title of the DatePicker (ex:month name) and use an if condition

```
// Validate the title, so that you can find whether the date picker is present or not 
if(monthname.isdisPlayed()) {
  ....
}
```

First, find what type of date picker is it.. If it's jQuery date picker you can inspect and handle it.

The calendar shown in the image below is a jQuery date picker:

[image: Date Picker]

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to `send keys` to that **input field :**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("enddate")).sendKeys("02/03/2005");
```